# Создание своего View

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view

Я создаю библиотеку в которой будит `view TimeView`.

Чтобы отображался текст на `View` нужно унаследоваться от `TextView`,  но тогда будет доступен метод `setText` в который можно впихнуть любой текст, но мне нужно чтобы туда можно было впихнуть только дату и время, то есть мне нужно скрыть метод `setText` от пользователя* и создать метод `setTime`.

Как скрыть метод `setText` от пользователя* или есть какой-то другой способ для решения этой проблемы?

**пользовател - програмист который будит пользоваться этой библиотекой**

Comment: Переопределите метод setText() в своем классе-наследнике и оформите там какую-нибудь заглушку

Comment: @pavloff пожалуйста привиди пример я буду сильно блогадарен. Я незнаю как зделать заглушку методу.

Comment: Скрыть метод от пользователя чего? Что вы хотите создать?

Comment: @НикитаЖуков А нет, так не получится. метод `setText()` в `TextView` финальный, его нельзя переопределить.

Comment: Если вас решительно не устраивает наличие метода `setText()`, то видимо вам нужно наследоваться выше по иерархии, не от `TextView`, а, например, от `View`. Если требуются многие функции `TextView`, то можно его скопировать из исходников и переписать под себя, в частности удалить методы `setText()` и добавить свои

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос немного корявый. Но вроде понятно. В свойствах **EditText** вам нужно установить атрибут `android:inputType` . И уже в нём указать то, что имеет право ввести пользователь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае вам нужно указать `android:inputType="datetime"`.

А выводить в TextView вы можете что угодно и как угодно

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, но это не то что я хотя. Я понимаю что вопрос корявый это из-за того что ситуация сложная. Постарой свормулировать вопрос точнеё.